# Database Design Architecture : A Notification - User Relationships in a NoSQL Database

Tags: database, relationship, entity-relationship, nosql

In my previous apps, I dealt with user notification tracking by keeping a `Notification` table that contained the notificatioons of all users and tracking it per user by having a `Sender` and `Receiver` column per user.

But I think that this architecture would turn out to be inefficient, slow and irrelevant when the user base is high. So, what could be the alternatives of this architecture? (Push notifications are there for without polling data fetch but I want them to be network retrievable and store in the database).

I thought of something like an **Inbox** architecture where there shall be column named `Notifications` and every new Json for A notification object might be appended on and on for the user as a JSON Array. But I don't know still if this is good.

I guess there are more experienced professionals who can guide me in this.

Thanks. :)